# What is the best approach to create an autoplay video scrollview with Swift?

Tags: ios, swift, uiscrollview, avplayer

I am working on an app a little like Vine.

In this app, I have a view controller where several videos are displayed in a scrollview. I would like to create the same concept as Vine, Facebook or Instagram where the current video is "autoplayed" when visible in the scrollview.

I am starting to think about it. First, what would be the best player to use in order to display the videos ? I need a "light" player because I will have to display multiple ones on the same controller with infinite scroll capatibility.

Then, it's not really clear for me, but here is how I "see" that working :

1. I have a scrollview with several video players in it
2. I detect with a scrollview function, the current visible item on the screen
3. When detected, I autoplay the video of this current item
4. If the user scrolls, I automatically pause the previous video to start the next visible one.

Is it the good approach ? And is it possible to do that ? And what should I use in the scrollview as a controller to display my video players ?

Thanks :-) !

Answer (score 0):

```
private ListView listView = null;

View getArticleListView()a
{
    listView = new ListView(context);

    listView.setAdapter(new ListAdaptor(context, titleList, descriptionList, pubDateList, thumbnailList, contentList, pageNumber));

    listView.setRecyclerListener(new AbsListView.RecyclerListener() {
        @Override
        public void onMovedToScrapHeap(View view) {
            View firstView = listView.getChildAt(0);

            if (ListAdaptor.videoPlayer != null)
                ListAdaptor.videoPlayer.stopPlayback();
        }
    });

    listView.setOnScrollListener(new AbsListView.OnScrollListener() {
        private int mFirstVisibleRow = 0;
        private int mActiveItem = 0;

        @Override
        public void onScrollStateChanged(AbsListView absListView, int i) {


                int firstVisibleRow = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
                if( mFirstVisibleRow != firstVisibleRow )
                {
                    mFirstVisibleRow = firstVisibleRow;


                    VideoView prevActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem); // Cancel the video of the previous active item
                    if( prevActiveVideoView != null )
                    {
                        prevActiveVideoView.setVisibility(View.INVISIBLE);
                        ListAdaptor.imgCardLitImage.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        ListAdaptor.imageVideoOverLay.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
                        prevActiveVideoView.pause();
                    }

                    // Start the video of the new active item
                    if(viewHeight > (listView.getChildAt(0).getHeight())/2 ){
                        mActiveItem = mFirstVisibleRow + 1;
                    }
                    else {
                        mActiveItem = mFirstVisibleRow;
                    }

                    final VideoView newActiveVideoView = getVideoViewForRow(mActiveItem);
                    if(newActiveVideoView != null)
                    {

                        newActiveVideoView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                        newActiveVideoView.setOnPreparedListener(new MediaPlayer.OnPreparedListener() {

                            @Override
                            public void onPrepared(MediaPlayer mediaPlayer) {
                                mediaPlayer.start();
                                        mediaPlayer.setVolume(0, 0);
                            }
                        });
                    }

                }

        }

        @Override
        public void onScroll(AbsListView view, int firstVisibleItem,
                             int visibleItemCount, int totalItemCount) {
            View v = listView.getChildAt(0);
            int top = (v == null) ? 0 : (listView.getPaddingTop() - v.getTop());
            viewHeight = top;

        }

        private VideoView getVideoViewForRow(int row)
        {
            int firstVisibleRow = listView.getFirstVisiblePosition();
            View rowView = listView.getChildAt(row-firstVisibleRow);
            return (rowView == null) ? null : (VideoView)rowView.findViewById(R.id.videoView);
        }


    });

    return listView;
}
```